# Auto-complete function does not work In the QGIS python editor

Tags: qgis, python

I use QGIS 2.14.3-Essen. The auto-complete function works without any problems in the python console, but it does not work in the QGIS python editor. I also tried it on another PC running QGIS 2.14.3 - essen-based, both of which worked well. I even tried to re-install QGIS, but still was not able to solve this problem.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

When you load the **Python Console**, there should be an *Options* button:

[image: Python console options]

Click this and look for the *Editor* section. Make sure the **Autocompletion** setting is checked and has a threshold >0:

[image: Autocompletion]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I confirmed my setting, Autocompletion threshold is "2".

Comment: @TJ - I am currently installing QGIS 2.14.3 (I had 2.14.1) so will test this and see if it still works :)

Comment: @TJ - Sorry, can't replicate your issue as it still works for me.